# Keep getting `ReExecutablePromise { _then: [], _fn: [Function], _taskPromise: null }` when using ReactSelector for TestCafe

Tags: reactjs, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I am trying to implement testing on a React website using TestCafe.  I want to print the various props/attributes using getReact().  However, when printing to the console, I always get `ReExecutablePromise { _then: [], _fn: [Function], _taskPromise: null }` instead.

Here is my code:

```
var sideBar = ReactSelector('Sidebar').getReact();
console.log(sideBar);
```

I've also tried to get an actual property:

```
sideBarprops = checkListPage.sideBar.getReact(({ props }) => props.isChecklistVisible);
console.log(sideBar);
```

Either item always prints `ReExecutablePromise { _then: [], _fn: [Function], _taskPromise: null }`

I need to be able to print the actual values of properties, classNames, state, Keys, etc of a ReactSelector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getReact()` return a Promise, which you need to resolve. You can either do this

```
ReactSelector('Sidebar').getReact().then(props => {
   console.log(props);
})
```

or this

```
var sideBar = ReactSelector('Sidebar').getReact();
console.log(await sideBar);
```

or this

```
var sideBar = await ReactSelector('Sidebar').getReact();
console.log(sideBar);
```